# Java8 lambda convert List to Map of Maps

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, java-stream

Is it possible to transform `List<Entry>` to `Map<Employee, Map<LocalDate, Entry>>` with one lambda expression?

```
public class Entry {
    Employee employee;
    LocalDate date;
}
```

So far i have came up with something like this:

```
entries.stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(Collectors.groupingBy(Entry::getEmployee), Collectors.groupingBy(Entry::getDate), Function.identity()));
```

But this gives a compilation error:

```
no suitable method found for 
toMap(java.util.stream.Collector<com.a.Entry,capture#1 of ?,java.util.Map<com.a.Employee,
java.util.List<com.a.Entry>>>‌​,java.util.stream.Co‌​llector<com.a.Entry,‌​capture#2 of ?, 
java.util.Map<java.time.LocalDate,java.util.List<com.a.Ent‌ry>>>,
java.util.func‌​tion.Function<java.l‌​ang.Object,java.lang‌​.Object>)
```

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure that Employee is a suitable key for a map? BTW, define "does not work".

Comment: compilation error:
no suitable method found for toMap(java.util.stream.Collector<com.a.Entry,capture#1 of ?,java.util.Map<com.a.Employee,java.util.List<com.a.Entry>>>,java.util.stream.Collector<com.a.Entry,capture#2 of ?,java.util.Map<java.time.LocalDate,java.util.List<com.a.Entry>>>,java.util.function.Function<java.lang.Object,java.lang.Object>)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Assuming `Entry` has getters and `Employee` overrides `hashCode()` and `equals()`:

```
Map<Employee, Map<LocalDate, Entry>> result = entries.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Entry::getEmployee,
                Collectors.toMap(Entry::getDate, Function.identity())));
```

Note that this will throw an exception if an employee has duplicate dates.

Comment: wicket, works perfectly. Exception on duplicates is expected behavior. Thank you

Comment: And what if i'd need `Map<String, Map<LocaleDate,Entry>>` where key for the map is Employee::getUsername

? Is it possible to manipulate the keys as well?

Comment: @przem Sure, just replace `Entry::getEmployee` with `entry -> entry.getEmployee().getUsername()`.

Comment: noooooo i cant be that simple!!! :-D
many many thanks! works like a dream